# Visual Studio runs unwanted code

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How can I make Visual Studio run a certain project? I have two projects and it runs the first one I created every time. I'm using VS 2013

Comment: Maybe you mean "a certain project in a solution"?

Comment: Select solution in Solution explorer, options, startup project.

Comment: Right click on the project you want to run and choose "Set as StartUp Project".

Comment: I don't have the "Set as StartUp Project" option

Comment: @ShaulAharon Are you right clicking on the project?  Maybe a screen shot of you solution layout would help.

Comment: @ShaulAharon do you right click on the project itself? See the screenshot below for more info

Comment: Don't reckon it should be on hold. A simple edit to change the vocabulary used is enough to make the question better already isn't it ??

Answer (score 6):

You simply have to right click on that project and then select "Set as StartUp Project".
This defines what project should be run/compiled whenever you run/compile.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]